# Python dict using logic input for truth tables

Tags: python, dictionary, logic, logical-operators

Alright boys and girls here we go. To start off I have a couple of questions. Since my program is large I will simply ask questions in stages, this question being the first. I'm creating a program that generates a truth table for postfix logical expressions. Here are the operators allowed and their logical equivalents:

```
Operators:
=                Logical Equivalence (≡ or ↔) 
`->` or `<=`     Logical Implication (→)
+                Disjunction (∨), AKA “or”
*                Conjunction (∧), AKA “and” 
`~` or `!`       Negation (¬), AKA “not”
```

Here are some examples of input and output:

```
input
p True =

output
p      p True =
False  False
True   True

input
p !

output
p      p !
False  True
True   False

input
p q =

output
p      q      p q =
False  False  True
False  True   False
True   False  False
True   True   True
```

Ok I don't really *know* where to begin, but I'm not asking for anybody to write this program for me. I know I need to write code using a Python dict, that matches the keys to the corresponding proposition. But how do I know which ones to put for keys and which ones to put for values? Also, in the case of:

```
`->` or `<=`     Logical Implication (→)
```

and

```
`~` or `!`       Negation (¬), AKA “not”
```

How do I assign 2 different inputs to be able to be used in a python dict? I hope this isn't too confusing, I'm very noob at python, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE
Ok here is the code I have now:

```
propositions = {
    '=' : (2, {(True, True): True,
              (True, False): False,
              (False, True) : False,
              (False, False): True,
              }),
    '->' : (2, {(True, True): True,
                (True, False): False,
                (False, True): True,
                (False, False): True,
                }),
    '+' : (2, {(True, True): True,
               (True, False): True,
               (False, True): True,
               (False, False): False,
               }),
    '*' : (2, {(True, True): True,
               (True, False): False,
               (False, True): False,
               (False, False): False,
               }),
    '!' : (1, {True: False,
               False: True})}

prop = sys.stdin.readline()
prop = prop.split()
prop = prop[::-1]
for x in prop:
```

I believe I successfully reversed the string and removed all whitespaces, but I am still a bit confused on iterating through it.

SECOND UPDATE here is my code:

```
propositions = {
    '=' : (2, {(True, True): True,
              (True, False): False,
              (False, True) : False,
              (False, False): True,
              }),
    '->' : (2, {(True, True): True,
                (True, False): False,
                (False, True): True,
                (False, False): True,
                }),
    '+' : (2, {(True, True): True,
               (True, False): True,
               (False, True): True,
               (False, False): False,
               }),
    '*' : (2, {(True, True): True,
               (True, False): False,
               (False, True): False,
               (False, False): False,
               }),
    '!' : (1, {True: False,
               False: True})}

prop = sys.stdin.readline()
prop = prop.strip().split()
prop = reversed(prop)
def evaluate():
    token = next(prop)
    try:
        nargs, table = propositions[token]
    except KeyError:
        if token.lower() in ('true', '1'):
            return True
        elif token.lower() in ('false', '0'):
            return False
        else:
            return token
    return table[tuple(evaluate() for i in range(nargs))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build your dicts in the order of resolution from outer to inner:

```
master_dict = {
   '=': (2, {(True, True): True,
             (True, False): False,
             ...
             }),
   ...
   '!': (1, {True: False,
             False: True})}
```

The numbers indicate how many operands the operator takes.

To parse an input read it from right to left.

Use a recursive function, that consumes one token from the right.

(1) If the token is an operator (i.e. a key in your dictionary) retrieve the corresponding value from your master dict.

The number stored first is the number of arguments the operator takes. So your function must now call itself as many times as there are arguments. Be sure to keep track of which tokens have already be read. One neat way of doing this is using a list iterator, which will spit out each element exactly once, so you can't get the indexing wrong. Once you have all the arguments you apply the truth table you've just retrieved, read out the result and return it.

(2) If the token is not an oprator your function must just return it.

```
prop = sys.stdin.readline()

def solve_no_var(prop):
    rev_iter = reversed(prop)
    def evaluate():
        token = next(rev_iter)
        try:
            nargs, table = propositions[token]
        except KeyError:
            if token.lower() in ('true', '1'):
                return True
            elif token.lower() in ('false', '0'):
                return False
            else:
                return token
        return table[tuple(evaluate() for i in range(nargs))]
    return evaluate()

def solve(prop):
    prop = prop.strip().split()
    variables = list(set(prop) - set(propositions)
        - {'True', 'TRUE', 'true', '1', 'False', 'FALSE', 'false', '0'})
    lookup = {v: [j for j, p in enumerate(prop) if p == v] for v in variables}
    N = len(variables)
    print((N*" {:6} ").format(*variables), 'result')
    for p in itertools.product(("True", "False"), repeat=N):
        prop_nv = prop.copy()
        for v, b in zip (variables, p):
            for j in lookup[v]:
                prop_nv[j] = b
        res = solve_no_var(prop_nv)
        print(((N+1)*" {:6} ").format(*(p + (res,))))

solve(prop)
```

Comment: Hey again. I believe I have built my dict correctly, now how can I go about reading the input? I know I need to use a stack.

Comment: @T.Dog Updated the post. Should get you started.

Comment: Hi again, I think I made a bit of progress, and I have updated my question at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I believe I changed it to what you specified but it's not working. I'll update my question. Thanks for helping

Comment: Sorry I should have specified what wasn't working. I am able to input things but nothing happens.

Comment: @T.Dog You have to call `evaluate()` in the end

Comment: p !
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tristan/PycharmProjects/yay/hellopython.py", line 218, in <module>
    evaluate()
  File "C:/Users/Tristan/PycharmProjects/yay/hellopython.py", line 216, in evaluate
    return table[tuple(evaluate() for i in range(nargs))]
KeyError: ('p',)

Comment: @T.Dog Ok if you want to allow variables you have to add another layer. I'll update the answer.